# Как использовать 1 метод для версии теста и для релизной версии

Tags: java, android

В RXJava для запуска цепочки нужен Scheduler. Дело в том что, при запуске метода содержайщий RX нужно запускать используя TestScheduler, а при обычном тестировании debug и release нужно использовать методы из Schedulers.

Так вот, есть ли способ в Android, чтобы можно было создать 1 метод к примеру `Schedulers.io();` и данный метод работал в debug и release как Schedulers.io.

А если я запускаю в тестах, к примеру в JUnit, то запускался второй метод с таким же названием Schedulers.io(), только в теле возвращется TestScheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Ну в общем говоря да, в RxJava есть плагинная система:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Plugins
Там вы сможете переопределить то что возвращает `Schedulers`

Но я бы посоветовал Вам вынести `Scheduler` в поле класса который содержит данный метод и получать нужный `Scheduler` в конструкторе, это более тестируемый и гибкий вариант.